# How to exit a function without exiting form when form is modal?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form which, among the other controls, has a TextBox field that can be optionally filled by user .
There is also a **btnSubmit Button** that performs required actions and closes the form .
In its code, I check if a comment is present and, if not so, ask the user if he wants to fill it before exiting .
I use a **bool AskToFillCommentIfNeeded()** function that displays a MessageBox asking user to optionally fill the comment before exiting if this has not been done already .
It returns true if user answered Yes, false otherwise .
If user clicks Yes, I must exit the submit function without closing the form, so user can enter the comment and then press submit button again .

The [edited] code is something like this :

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // ask user if he wants to fill the comment : if so, exit this function
     if (AskToFillCommentIfNeeded()) { return; };

     // ... save data and exit form ...
}
```

I use this code in a non modal form and it works as expected .
But when I try to use it in a modal form with btnSubmit DialogResult property set to OK,
it does not work as expected :
instead of just exiting the event sink, it closes the form
without saving data .

I made up a (clumsy) workaround, using a boolean flag like this :

```
private bool isBusy = false;
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // clumsy attempt to avoid form exit :
     isBusy = true;

     // ask user if he wants to fill the comment : if so, exit this function
     if (AskToFillCommentIfNeeded()) { return; };

     isBusy = false;

      // ... save data and exit form ...
}
```

Thus, if the return statement is executed, I intercept the _FormClosing event
and cancel it if the flag is set to true :

```
private void FDialog_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
     // abort closing if flag is set
     e.Cancel = isBusy;
}
```

This works, but it is less than satisfactory .
Is there a better way to achieve the same behaviour ?
I am using C# Express 2010 .
Thank you in advance .

jack griffin

Comment: Thank for your prompt answer .

Comment: You can delete comments. And you don't have to thank every poster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the form's DialogResult property back to None to prevent the dialog from closing:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (AskToFillCommentIfNeeded()) {
         this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None; 
         return;
     }

     // ... save data and exit form ...
}
```

Comment: Thank for your prompt answer .

Comment: Such a simple answer and yet I missed it completely! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Set `button.DialogResult = None` and assign `form.DialogResult` property in the `button.Click` event manually.

Comment: Thank for your prompt answer .

Comment: This works but is not the correct solution.  The OK button no longer looks like the dialog's default button, note the missing heavy border.

Answer (score 0):

Note : I would have post this right now, but beeing new on the forum
I must wait 8 hours before answer to my own questions .
Still, I feel that a post is better than just leaving comments to
each answer in this case.
( I mean that my thanks were to reach you immediately :-) ) .

Thank you for your faster-than-light answers !
They were very illuminating .
@Hans Passant : This was exactly the solution I was after .
@mrtofigh : changing button.DialogResult won' t work, it must be form.DialogResult .
@Henk Holterman : You are right about the close button in the title bar .
If user clicks it, though, the application will assume that user does not intend to
submit anything .
To be sure of this, I will add this code :

```
private void FDialog_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // intercept form closing from Close box in title bar
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
             e.Cancel = !ConfirmFormExit();
        }
}
```

where **ConfirmFormExit()** is a bool function showing a MessageBox asking user if he wants to quit without submitting and returns true on Yes .

Thus, the code will be :

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //  avoid form exit right now
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;

    // ask user if he wants to fill the comment : if so, exit this function 
    if (AskToFillCommentIfNeeded()) { return; };

    // now is safe to return dialog result
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

    // ... save data and exit form       
}
```

I tested it and it works just fine .
Thank you again .
Jack